# Python- Add dynamic number of columns to sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to python and working on a project in which i need to create dynamic number of columns in table in a database.
For example,

```
User input = 5    
Output=
Database:
    table:
        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
```

Before this, I was creating dynamic number of tables using this loop:

```
for w in range(number + 1):
        IP.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table' + str(w) + '(column REAL)')
```

But now I do not need to create tables but want to add dynamic columns. I tried using similar loop but it does not work. Can anyone help me with this as I don't know much about sqlite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a CHAR(20) column to an existing table `x` with the SQL statement

```
alter table x add column colName CHAR(20);
```

By writing a loop to construct the column names you can add as many as you want.

Comment: thats right thanks! and even we can add column of any type as i have used type REAL.

Comment: Sure - this was just an example to get you started